# Challange with GeoServer version 2.23.2

Tags: geoserver

Regarding GeoServer version 2.23.2

By posting to featuretypes with this payload we are able to create a layer in our geoserver:

```
<featureType>
    <name>elm_road_M</name>
    <nativeName>elm_road</nativeName>
    <namespace>
        <name>demo</name>
        
    </namespace>
    <title>elm_road_M</title>
    <keywords>
        <string>features</string>
        <string>elm_road_M</string>
    </keywords>
    <nativeCRS>GEOGCS[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, DATUM[&quot;World Geodetic System 1984&quot;, SPHEROID[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;7030&quot;]], AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;6326&quot;]], PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;, 0.0, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;8901&quot;]], UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;, 0.017453292519943295], AXIS[&quot;Geodetic longitude&quot;, EAST], AXIS[&quot;Geodetic latitude&quot;, NORTH], AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;4326&quot;]]</nativeCRS>
    <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
    <nativeBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </nativeBoundingBox>
    <latLonBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </latLonBoundingBox>
    <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <metadata>
        <entry key="JDBC_VIRTUAL_TABLE">
            <virtualTable>
                <name>elm_road_M</name>
                <sql>select r.id, f.labeltext, r.chainage0, r.geometry from _demo.elm_road r inner join _demo.foo f on r.id=f.road_id</sql>
                <escapeSql>false</escapeSql>
                <keyColumn>id</keyColumn>
                <geometry>
                    <name>geometry</name>
                    <type>LineString</type>
                    <srid>4326</srid>
                </geometry>
            </virtualTable>
        </entry>
    </metadata>
    <store class="dataStore">
        <name>demo:demo:demo</name>
        
    </store>
    <serviceConfiguration>false</serviceConfiguration>
    <simpleConversionEnabled>false</simpleConversionEnabled>
    <internationalTitle/>
    <internationalAbstract/>
    <maxFeatures>0</maxFeatures>
    <numDecimals>0</numDecimals>
    <padWithZeros>false</padWithZeros>
    <forcedDecimal>false</forcedDecimal>
    <overridingServiceSRS>false</overridingServiceSRS>
    <skipNumberMatched>false</skipNumberMatched>
    <circularArcPresent>false</circularArcPresent>
</featureType>
```

When we after creation run the GetFeatureType we get this:

```
<featureType>
    <name>elm_road_M</name>
    <nativeName>elm_road</nativeName>
        <title>elm_road_M</title>
    <keywords>
        <string>features</string>
        <string>elm_road_M</string>
    </keywords>
    <nativeCRS>GEOGCS[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 
  DATUM[&quot;World Geodetic System 1984&quot;, 
    SPHEROID[&quot;WGS 84&quot;, 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;7030&quot;]], 
    AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;6326&quot;]], 
  PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;, 0.0, AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;8901&quot;]], 
  UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;, 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS[&quot;Geodetic longitude&quot;, EAST], 
  AXIS[&quot;Geodetic latitude&quot;, NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY[&quot;EPSG&quot;,&quot;4326&quot;]]</nativeCRS>
    <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
    <nativeBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </nativeBoundingBox>
    <latLonBoundingBox>
        <minx>-180.0</minx>
        <maxx>180.0</maxx>
        <miny>-90.0</miny>
        <maxy>90.0</maxy>
        <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </latLonBoundingBox>
    <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <metadata>
        <entry key="JDBC_VIRTUAL_TABLE">
            <virtualTable>
                <name>elm_road_M</name>
                <sql>select r.id, f.labeltext, r.chainage0, r.geometry from _demo.elm_road r inner join _demo.foo f on r.id=f.road_id
</sql>
                <escapeSql>false</escapeSql>
                <keyColumn>id</keyColumn>
                <geometry>
                    <name>geometry</name>
                    <type>LineString</type>
                    <srid>4326</srid>
                </geometry>
            </virtualTable>
        </entry>
    </metadata>
    <store class="dataStore">
        <name>demo:demo</name>
        
    </store>
    <serviceConfiguration>false</serviceConfiguration>
    <simpleConversionEnabled>false</simpleConversionEnabled>
    <maxFeatures>0</maxFeatures>
    <numDecimals>0</numDecimals>
    <padWithZeros>false</padWithZeros>
    <forcedDecimal>false</forcedDecimal>
    <overridingServiceSRS>false</overridingServiceSRS>
    <skipNumberMatched>false</skipNumberMatched>
    <circularArcPresent>false</circularArcPresent>
    <attributes>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.String</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>chainage0</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>java.lang.String</binding>
        </attribute>
        <attribute>
            <name>geometry</name>
            <minOccurs>0</minOccurs>
            <maxOccurs>1</maxOccurs>
            <nillable>true</nillable>
            <binding>org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString</binding>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</featureType>
```

As you can see the layer is not having attributes corresponding to what is mentioned in SQL statement. (`select r.id, f.labeltext, r.chainage0, r.geometry from _demo.elm_road r inner join _demo.foo f on r.id=f.road_id`)

The problem is that we can’t publish the layer with a style referring to the missing attribute (in this case `labeltext`).

The problem gets fixed if we inspect the layer in geoserver UI including pressing the <kbd>Edit sql view</kbd> button.

Just if needed – here is the SLD

```
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>Red Line</sld:Title>
      <sld:Abstract>Light red line, 2px wide</sld:Abstract>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Title>Roads</sld:Title>
          <sld:LineSymbolizer>
            <sld:Stroke>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#AA3333</sld:CssParameter>
              <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">5</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Stroke>
          </sld:LineSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
         <Rule>
          <Title>Rule Text Symbolize</Title>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>10000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>labeltext</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">15</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
             </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <PointPlacement>
                <AnchorPoint>
                  <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
                  <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                </AnchorPoint>
              </PointPlacement>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <VendorOption name="autoWrap">60</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="spaceAround">20</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0.0</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: You can do a GET to fetch a correct XML document for a feature type to use as your base